# Keys do not move sprite properly in pygame, strange behavior

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been exparimenting with pygame, I can draw my sprite, but when I press WASD I have to press them all many times, and all the sprite does is move down and side to side, with no real control

I update the `self.rect` in the sprite class, and when you press a key it clears the screen and should redraw the sprite with a different x y position.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = demon
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        self.rect.x += moveX
        self.rect.y += moveY
        
        

        
        
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

demon = pygame.image.load("C:/programming/doomman/cacodemon.png").convert_alpha()

x = 300
y = 300

my_sprite = Sprite((x, y))
all_sprites_list.add(my_sprite)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Demon Dance")
carryOn = True
        
while carryOn == True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                carryOn=False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                screen.fill(BLACK)
                if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    my_sprite.update(50, 0)
                if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    my_sprite.update(-50, 0)
                if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    my_sprite.update(0, 50)
                if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    my_sprite.update(0, 50)
    
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) returns a list with the state of all keyboard buttons. This is not intended to get the key of a keyboard event. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object:

```py
while carryOn == True:
    # [...]
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                my_sprite.update(50, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                my_sprite.update(-50, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                my_sprite.update(0, 50)
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                my_sprite.update(0, 50)

    # [...]
```

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) returns a list with the state of all keyboard buttons. This is not intended to get the key of a keyboard event. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object.

However, you  must evaluate the keys in the application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
while carryOn == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        my_sprite.update(50, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        my_sprite.update(-50, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        my_sprite.update(0, 50)
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        my_sprite.update(0, 50)

    # [...]
```